# Summing Rows by grouping two columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by

I have a data base of firearm background checks conducted the original data had months but not in separate columns so I changed the column name to years and now have 12 rows for each year for each state. I would like to summarize the total checks conducted in the other columns by using state and year. I've tried some variations of group_by and summarize and also aggregate. When i ran

```
gunData <-aggregate(.~year+state,gunData, sum)
```

It seemed to work but erased most of the years and states. Is there a limit on the amount of variables that can get aggregated any help is appreciated.

```
 year state                permit permit_recheck handgun long_gun other multiple totals
   <dbl> <chr>                 <dbl>          <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>
 1  2021 Alabama               31803            512   20970    16026  1548      959  74710
 2  2021 Alaska                  222              1    3055     2564   375      189   6667
 3  2021 Arizona                9290           1159   20530     9991  1754     1114  45496
 4  2021 Arkansas               3123           1152    7068     5289   448      390  18916
 5  2021 California            16025          11953   40789    27915  6499        0 119784
 6  2021 Colorado              10891              6   21729    13839  1960     1760  50485
 7  2021 Connecticut            9792            476    6046     1996  1438        0  19748
 8  2021 Delaware                353              0    2775     1563   158      153   5245
 9  2021 District of Columbia    538              1     304        4     0        2    920
10  2021 Florida               31875              0   66307    26720  5116     2894 138870
# ... with 14,730 more rows
```

Here is a table with the months labeled maybe it will help explain what i mtryign to do

```
A tibble: 14,740 x 10
   year  month state                permit permit_recheck handgun long_gun other multiple totals
   <chr> <chr> <chr>                 <dbl>          <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 2021  02    Alabama               31803            512   20970    16026  1548      959  74710
 2 2021  02    Alaska                  222              1    3055     2564   375      189   6667
 3 2021  02    Arizona                9290           1159   20530     9991  1754     1114  45496
 4 2021  02    Arkansas               3123           1152    7068     5289   448      390  18916
 5 2021  02    California            16025          11953   40789    27915  6499        0 119784
 6 2021  02    Colorado              10891              6   21729    13839  1960     1760  50485
 7 2021  02    Connecticut            9792            476    6046     1996  1438        0  19748
 8 2021  02    Delaware                353              0    2775     1563   158      153   5245
 9 2021  02    District of Columbia    538              1     304        4     0        2    920
10 2021  02    Florida               31875              0   66307    26720  5116     2894 138870
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Are you saying you want it to display more of the resulting data frame?  That's a lot of rows to print.

Comment: No im trying to consolidate it. I want to get yearly totals out of the monthly totals

Comment: Your code looks fine. The result is probably fine too - doublecheck it please. If you need more help, please post an example that demonstrates and reproduces the problem.

Comment: It's a little confusing trying to follow your question. Like the others said, try to make your question reproducible. Include a sample dataset (use `dput`), show your attempt and provide your desired output based on your sample.

Comment: What do you mean by "erased most of the years"?